# Javascript XSL Transformation on Internet Explorer 11 not working when XSL contains Imports

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xslt

I'm creating a simple `HTML + javascript` page that allows the user to load a specific type of XML file that will be transformed into HTML by XSL transformation.

It works pretty well in `Chrome/Firefox/Edge`, but it fails on `IE 11` returning just the text of the XML without any formatting.

My suspect is that the issue is in the `<xsl:import/>` in the main xsl file.

I created a plunker to show you the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/2HNIOZ

If you run i ton Chrome, it will show a table with a list of artists/songs.

If you run it in  Internet Explorer, it will show just a bunch of unformatted text.

if you change line 34 from:

```
xslDoc.load('cdcatalog.xsl');
```

to:

```
xslDoc.load('cdcatalog_imported.xsl');
```

You'll see that the xml is printed the correct way like it is in Chrome.

I'm really lost on this since I have no idea how to debug this issue.

Thank you for any help :)

---

PS:
I'm not an expert with this tool, so I wasn't able to publicly share the xml and the two xsl files i used so I'll share it here:

**cdcatalog.xsl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:import href="cdcatalog_imported.xsl"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**cdcatalog_imported.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>


<h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**catalog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
  </cd>
  ...
</catalog>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763800(v=vs.85).aspx

I had to enable resolveExternals.

To solve my case I had the following code after line 43:

```
xslDoc.resolveExternals = true;
```